# Poor Performance on Windows Server 2016 with MySQL ODBC Connector

Tags: mysql, performance, asp-classic, odbc

I am currently migrating some applications from a server (Windows Server 2008 64 bits) to another one (Windows Server 2016 Standard 64 bits).

These applications are :

- ASP.NET MVC websites
- MySQL 5.5.58
- Classic ASP websites which have been generated by [ASPRunner Professional](https://www.xlinesoft.com/asprunnerpro).

I have performance problems with these classic ASP websites. They use the MySQL ODBC Connector (version 3.51) to fetch data from the MySQL database.

For example, in the database, there is a Car table with 4000 entries.
It takes less than 1 second to load them through MySQL Workbench. But through the classic ASP website, it takes 5 minutes !

The connection string used is

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=xxx;Database=db_name;OPTION=3
```

I tried the things below to solve my problem, without any success :

- I tried with the 32 and 64 bits version of the ODBC connector.
- After reading [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/488206), I tried to set the SERVER value with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Some of the ASP.NET MVC Websites use the same database with Entity Framework and they don't have any performance problem.
The classic applications work very well on Windows Server 2008 so I wonder how can I troubleshoot the problem on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Is the ASP website client on the same server as the MySQL server?  If not, where are each located?

Comment: Both are on the same server (Windows Server 2016).

Comment: What were the actual SQL statements involved?  Was it a single connection for the entire load?  Or a new connection for each row?